# Using the same FK twice on the same table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a table `Inspection_tbl` with a column `ApprovedBy` or `Personnel_ID (FK)` which references the `Personnel_tbl`. The table also has another column `InspectedBy` or `Personnel_ID (FK)` which also references the `Personnel_tbl`.

Is referencing the same table twice (`Personnel_tbl`) from one table (`Inspection_tbl`) not allowed, since I'm going to have the same column (`Personnel_ID (FK)`)?

I am very new to SQL and I am fond to accept any solution to address this problem.. Thank you very much...

Comment: As far as I know there should be no issue as long as the two foreign key fields are named differently. There is no issue with referencing the same table in two different foreign key constraints. Just make sure the fields and constraints have different names.

Comment: Yes, the name of a foreign key column can be different than the name of the referenced primary key column.

Comment: Did you try it? It would be quicker than posting on Stack Overflow..

Answer (score 0):

> Is referencing the same table twice (Personnel_tbl) from one table (Inspection_tbl) not allowed

The way to think about this is to think about what the FK relationship *means*.  A foreign key defines a *domain*: `A references T(B)` means that *A* must appear in *B*.  If it does not, it's not of the type -- i.e. not of the domain -- that *B* defines.

Is there a rule that says 2 columns in a table cannot have the same domain?  There is not.  Normalization is orthogonal to types.

You are saying `ApprovedBy` and `InspectedBy` are both constrained to the domain defined by `Personnel_tbl.Personnel_ID`.  If that's what you mean, you're in good shape.  :-)